# Bootstrap modal with tabs dynamic position/height

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm using jschr bootstrap modal plugin (https://github.com/jschr/bootstrap-modal) to create modals on my site.  First of all, I love the plugin, it makes the modal do all the cool stuff I wish it did, but I'm using the modals in the following manner that isn't quite working out how I want:

Basically, I want to implement dynamic position on the modal when the modal contains tabs.  So, in the example below, the modal will currently ALWAYS be set @ the position of the first active tab, regardless of the length of the content in the additional tabs.  Basically, what I'm after is when the tab changes for the modal to reposition into the center of the window with it's new height... any ideas on how to accomplish this?

```
<a href="#CustomerDetailsModal" data-toggle="modal">Open modal</a>

<div id="CustomerDetailsModal" class="modal hide" >
<div class="modal-header">
    <button data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button">×</button>
    <h3>Customer Details</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body" >
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#CustomerDetails">MY CUSTOMER</a></li>
<li ><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Users">Users</a></li>
<li ><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Activity">OUTRAGEOUSLY LONG CONTENT HERE.</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="customerdetails" >

<div id="CustomerDetails" class="tab-pane active" >

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="control-group">     
    <div class="control-label">
            Company
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
        <span class="detailsDisplay">CUSTOMER INFO</span>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="control-group">     
    <div class="control-label">
            CompanyAlias
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
        <span class="detailsDisplay"></span>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="control-group">     
    <div class="control-label">
            Address
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
        <span class="detailsDisplay">123 ME ST</span>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="control-group">     
    <div class="control-label">
            City
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
        <span class="detailsDisplay">SURFSIDE BEACH</span>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="control-group">     
    <div class="control-label">
            State
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
        <span class="detailsDisplay">SC</span>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="control-group">     
    <div class="control-label">
            Zip
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
        <span class="detailsDisplay">29575</span>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="control-group">     
    <div class="control-label">
            Phone
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
        <span class="detailsDisplay">555-555-5555</span>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="control-group">     
    <div class="control-label">
            Bill To Email
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
        <span class="detailsDisplay">CUSTOMER@EMAIL</span>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="Users" class="tab-pane" >
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Create Date</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>E-mail</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
                <td>9/9/2013 10:14:48 PM</td>
                <td>MY</td>
                <td>CUSTOMER</td>
                <td>CUSTOMER@EMAIL.COM</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div id="Activity" class="tab-pane" style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <TR><TD>SOME CONTENT</TD><TD>SOME MORE CONTENT</TD>
        <TR><TD>SOME CONTENT</TD><TD>SOME MORE CONTENT</TD>
        <TR><TD>SOME CONTENT</TD><TD>SOME MORE CONTENT</TD>
        <TR><TD>SOME CONTENT</TD><TD>SOME MORE CONTENT</TD>
        <TR><TD>SOME CONTENT</TD><TD>SOME MORE CONTENT</TD>
        <TR><TD>SOME CONTENT</TD><TD>SOME MORE CONTENT</TD>
        <TR><TD>SOME CONTENT</TD><TD>SOME MORE CONTENT</TD>
        <TR><TD>SOME CONTENT</TD><TD>SOME MORE CONTENT</TD>
        <TR><TD>SOME CONTENT</TD><TD>SOME MORE CONTENT</TD>
        <TR><TD>SOME CONTENT</TD><TD>SOME MORE CONTENT</TD>
        <TR><TD>SOME CONTENT</TD><TD>SOME MORE CONTENT</TD>
        <TR><TD>SOME CONTENT</TD><TD>SOME MORE CONTENT</TD>
        <TR><TD>SOME CONTENT</TD><TD>SOME MORE CONTENT</TD>
        <TR><TD>SOME CONTENT</TD><TD>SOME MORE CONTENT</TD>
        <TR><TD>SOME CONTENT</TD><TD>SOME MORE CONTENT</TD>
        <TR><TD>SOME CONTENT</TD><TD>SOME MORE CONTENT</TD>
        <TR><TD>SOME CONTENT</TD><TD>SOME MORE CONTENT</TD>
        <TR><TD>SOME CONTENT</TD><TD>SOME MORE CONTENT</TD>
        <TR><TD>SOME CONTENT</TD><TD>SOME MORE CONTENT</TD>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <a data-dismiss="modal" class="btn" href="#">Close</a>
</div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: I added a fiddle you can get to here:  http://jsfiddle.net/valvemail/ML6Xp/3/

Unfortunately it's a poor representation of what I'm doing because the modal opens docked at the top of the fiddle browser window thingy.... so, in the fiddle, the height is dynamic, but the position is not....

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So, a kindred spirit ran into a similar issue today and posted on bootstrap modal's github.  The solution is this https://github.com/jschr/bootstrap-modal/issues/207

```
/* after the tab changes:
$("#CustomerDetailsModal").modal('layout');
```

and presto chango it recenters.